# SQL Aggregation with SUM, GROUP BY and JOIN (many-to-many)

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum, aggregation

Here's an example Table layout:

```
TABLE_A:                    TABLE_B:     TABLE_A_B:
id | a     | b    | c       id | name    a_id | b_id
---------------------       ---------    -----------
1  | true  | X    | A       1  | A       1    | 1
2  | true  | Z    | null    2  | B       1    | 2
3  | false | X    | null    3  | C       2    | 2
4  | true  | Y    | Q                    4    | 1
5  | false | null | null                 4    | 2
                                         5    | 1
```

Possible Values:

- TABLE_A.a: true, false
- TABLE_A.b: X, Y, Z
- TABLE_A.c: A, B, C, ... basically arbitrary
- TABLE_B.name: A, B, C, ... basically arbitrary

**What I want to achieve:**

```
SELECT all rows from TABLE_A
  SUM(where a = true),
  SUM(where a = false),
  SUM(where b = 'X'),
  SUM(where b = 'Y'),
  SUM(where b = 'Z'),
  SUM(where b IS NULL),
and also get the SUMs for all distinct TABLE_A.c values.
and also get the SUMs for all those TABLE_A_B relations.
```

The result for the example Table above should look like:

```
aTrue | aFalse | bX | bY | bZ | bNull | cA | cQ | cNull | nameA | nameB | nameC
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3     | 2      | 2  | 1  | 1  | 1     | 1  | 1  | 3     | 3     | 3     | 0
```

**What I've done so far:**

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN a = true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS aTrue,
  SUM(CASE WHEN b = false THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS aFalse,
  SUM(CASE WHEN b = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bX,
  ...
FROM TABLE_A
```

**What's my problem?**

Selecting column `TABLE_A.a` and `TABLE_A.b` is easy, because there's a fixed number of possible values.

But I can't figure out how to count the distinct values of `TABLE_A.c`. And basically the same problem for the JOINed `TABLE_B`, **because** the number of values within `TABLE_B` is unknown and can change over time.

**Thanks for your help! `:)`**

### EDIT1: New (preferred) SQL result structure:

```
column         | value | sum
----------------------------
TABLE_A.a      | true  | 3
TABLE_A.a      | false | 2
TABLE_A.b      | X     | 2
TABLE_A.b      | Y     | 1
TABLE_A.b      | Z     | 1
TABLE_A.b      | null  | 1
TABLE_A.c      | A     | 1
TABLE_A.c      | Q     | 1
TABLE_A.c      | null  | 3
TABLE_B.name   | A     | 3
TABLE_B.name   | B     | 3
TABLE_B.name   | C     | 0
```

Comment: Why do you need the result in this format?

Comment: I don't need exactly this format, it would be also okay to have a key-value list as result: `key | value` and then rows `aTrue | 3`, `aFalse | 2`, `...`. The most important thing is that my application can read it and can identify the different keys.

Comment: Your application? Tell us more.

Comment: What do you need to know? It's based on Java (Spring Framework / JPA 2.1). This means: I can basically handle every result. I'll append a sample SQL Result structure to the question above. This new structure would be really cool to handle, but I don't know how to get there...

Comment: Ah, the new preferred structure is much easier for MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your original request of rows as a simulated pivot.  By doing a SUM( logical condition ) basically returns 1 if true, 0 if false.  So, since the column "a" is true or false, simple sum of "a" or NOT "a" (for the false counts -- NOT FALSE = TRUE).  Similarly, your "b" column, so b='X' = true counted as 1, else 0.

In other sql engines, you might see it as SUM( case/when ).

Now, since your table counts don't rely on each other, they can be separate SUM() into their own sub-alias query references (pqA and pqB for pre-queryA and pre-queryB respectively).  Since no group by, they will each result in a single row.  With no join will create a Cartesian, but since 1:1 ratio, will only return a single record of all columns you want.

```
SELECT 
      pqA.*, pqB.*
   from
      ( SELECT
              SUM( ta.a ) aTrue,
              SUM( NOT ta.a ) aFalse,
              SUM( ta.b = 'X' ) bX,
              SUM( ta.b = 'Y' ) bY,
              SUM( ta.b = 'Z' ) bZ,
              SUM( ta.b is null ) bNULL,
              SUM( ta.c = 'A' ) cA,
              SUM( ta.c = 'Q' ) cQ,
              SUM( ta.c is null ) cNULL,
              COUNT( distinct ta.c ) DistC
           from
              table_a ta ) pqA,
      ( SELECT
              SUM( b.Name = 'A' ) nameA,
              SUM( b.Name = 'B' ) nameB,
              SUM( b.Name = 'C' ) nameC
           from
              table_a_b t_ab 
                 join table_b b
                    ON t_ab.b_id = b.id ) pqB
```

This option gives your second (preferred) output

```
SELECT
      MAX( 'TABLE_A.a   ' ) as Basis,
      CASE when a then 'true' else 'false' end Value,
      COUNT(*) finalCnt
   from
      TABLE_A
   group by
      a
UNION ALL
SELECT
      MAX( 'TABLE_A.b   ' ) as Basis,
      b Value,
      COUNT(*) finalCnt
   from
      TABLE_A
   group by
      b
UNION ALL
SELECT
      MAX( 'TABLE_A.c   ' ) as Basis,
      c Value,
      COUNT(*) finalCnt
   from
      TABLE_A
   group by
      c
UNION ALL
SELECT
      MAX( 'TABLE_B.name   ' ) as Basis,
      b.Name Value,
      COUNT(*) finalCnt
   from
      table_a_b t_ab 
         join table_b b
            ON t_ab.b_id = b.id 
   group by
      b.Name
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution for output #2 looks basically like my first attempt (not shown here), where I just did a separate query for every column. Isn't #2 much slower than #1, because in #1 he just goes through the table once and for #2 it goes though the table for each UNION? `...` and one last question, what does the `MAX(...)` function do in there? I know you select the column name, but why do you use `MAX`?

Comment: @BenjaminM, since GROUP BY clauses require you to group by all non-aggregate columns, and the title isn't changing, some engines don't allow you to order by a computed column name.  So, a simple was to MAX( description ) since it was never changing anyhow and would satisfy the GROUP BY nagging.  Also, correct #1 faster as it goes through each table ONCE and gets ALL columns needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think You will need to build dynamic query as you don't know possible values for column C in table A. So you can write store procedure where you can get list of distinct value for Column C in one variable and by using "Do WHILE" you can construct your dynamic query.
Please let me know if you need more help in detail
[Dynamic SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: Thank you. I got your point. That solves the problem for `TABLE_A.c`, but what about the many-to-many relation between TABLE_A and TABLE_B? I tried to work with `LEFT JOIN TABLE_A_B ON ...` but then the SUM values become wrong, because the result of the JOIN can contain multiple rows for a single row of TABLE_A.

Comment: Will be helpful if you can share how you fix it.

Comment: @HappyCoder please show me your code so may be I can help you.. I think you should use sub query